# sed JSON regular expression

Tags: json, regex, sed

Apologize for such dummy question but this is my first time using `curl` command and now I got this command from somewhere to extract the following string

> {"success":true,"results":1,"total":1,"more":false,"offset":0,"hits":[{"path":"/home/users/Vq7DPVRHzGVK--OTJsHs","excerpt":"","name":"Vq7DPVRHzGVK--OTJsHs","title":"Vq7DPVRHzGVK--OTJsHs","lastModified":"2017-03-03
>   16:45:46","created":"2017-03-03 16:45:46"}]}

I pipe the `curl` output to `sed` with the following script:

```
sed -e 's/^.*"path":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/
```

Result:

> /home/users/Vq7DPVRHzGVK--OTJsHs

Can anyone explain how's the regex work here? and how do I get the result for only **Vq7DPVRHzGVK--OTJsHs** instead of including the /home/user path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation:

```
s/   ^.*"path":"\([^"]*\)".*$   /  \1   /
      ----------^------------     ---^---
             Pattern         Replacement string
```

How does Regular Expression work:

```
^.*         # Match beginning of input string & anything else
"path":"    # Up to literal string `"path":"`
\([^"]*\)   # Then match slash and match + group anything up to a double quote `"`
".*$        # Match double quote and the rest of input string
```

By replacement string `\1` you are replacing whole matching part with first capturing group which is every thing between double quotes of path value except the beginning slash.

What you want is changing capturing group from capturing whole part to last section:

```
s/^.*"path":"[^"]*\/\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/
```

Comment: @SLePort I am doing all right except the appreciation and compliment to revo, right?

Comment: @DEN Sorry, too quick comment. I didn't see you were an experienced user...

Answer (score 0):

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qb4ny2/1)

Regex: `.*"path\":"\K[\/\w]+(?=\/)\/\K[^"]+`

Comment: i got this error in return sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command

Comment: SED doesn't support PCRE.

Comment: Welcome @DEN  :)