# How to extract text with sed or grep and regular expression json

Tags: bash, curl, sed, expression

Hello I am using curl to get some info which I need to clean up.
This is from curl command:

```
{"ip":"000.000.000.000","country":"Italy","city":"Milan","longitude":9.1889,"latitude":45.4707, etc..
```

I would need to get "Ita" as output, that is the first three letter of the country.

After reading [sed JSON regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663370/sed-json-regular-expression) i tried to adapt resulting in

```
sed -e 's/^.*"country":"[a-zA-Z]{3}".*$/\1/
```

but this won't work.

Can you please help?

Comment: Use `sed -E 's/.*"country":"([a-zA-Z]{3}).*/\1/' file`. Or, `grep -Po '"country":"\K[A-Za-z]{3}' file`

Comment: Not recommended. Use a JSON parser, such as [tag:jq]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), you can do:

```
curl .... | jq -r '.country[0:3]'
```

If you need to ***set*** the country to the first 3 chars,

```
jq '.country = .country[0:3]'
```

---

some fairly advanced bash:

```
{
    read country
    read city
} < <(
    curl ... |
    jq -r '.country[0:3], .city[0:3]' 
)
```

Then:

```
$ echo "$country $city"
Ita Mil
```

Comment: thank you so much this is so much easier!
can i ask you how you would go to assign for example "Ita" and "Mil" to two different variables, running only once the curl command?

Comment: i just get an error: syntax error near unexpected token `<' : `} < <('
<

Comment: You need to be using bash or ksh (or maybe zsh), but not `sh`. The `< <(...)` is a redirection from a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)